# My link dosn't appear correct. How to remove the "" from link?

Tags: html

when I send message to user `<a href="www.link.com"> new link </a>`

then when user try to click on it
redirect to this address in browser: "www.link.com"

How can send the code to appears without "" in user side?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the behavior you describe.  Can you update the question to include an example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Did you actually check the source code and what exactly is sent to the browser? Are you sure that it's not something like `href='"www.link.com"'` or `href="%22www.link.com%22"`?

Comment: Actually if I set href="www.link.com" then appears to the browser https://mywebsite.com/"www.link.com"

Comment: That because (as I've said) without the protocol, the system is going to look for a ***file*** (not a website) named: www.link.com. That's fine if you want to link to a file that's part of your site (like another page: `<a href="somePage.html">`), but not when you want to link to another site. And, as I've said, you must have some other code causing the quotes that you are not showing.

Comment: After I check in Database appears in this format: <a href=\"www.link.com\">New </a >

Answer (score 1):

You must include the protocol in the address:

```
 <a href="http://www.link.com">
```

or:

```
 <a href="https://www.link.com">
```

Otherwise, the browser just sees "www.link.com" as a file name and tries to load that.

Here's a working example:

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com">Click here to go to Example.com</a>
```

Comment: Interesting that you have voted to close the question as well as answering it.

Comment: No, is not depend on https or http . whatever link I put there then appears with "" in browser

Comment: @NigelRen The original question did not show the HTML because it wasn't marked as code in the question, so I voted to close. I then realized that the code was there and edited the question to show it, but by then, it was too late to retract my close vote.

Comment: @JohnMartins That is not behavior that would happen if you code as I've shown. You must have a different issue causing this. And yes, you ***must*** include the protocol, otherwise the system will be looking for a file, not a website.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your replies.